# Two measurables leading to one immeasurable

Tags: geometry

In practice (and computationally), if we can accurately measure two 1 m long ropes and can make accurate right angle ($90^o $) by them constructing a right angle triangle in a physical world, why we cannot accurately measure, in practice (and computationally) the hypotenuse of such constructed triangle. why? Perhaps more of a question of mathematical philosophy than mathematics itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "exact" when you write "accurate".

And we *can't* measure $1$ meter exactly. There will always be some measurement uncertainty, as well as physical fuzziness of the thing you claim to be measuring; the atoms things are made of don't have crisp edges.

You may say that we can *speak about* $1$ meter exactly. That's true as far as it goes, but doesn't really create a problem, because we can *also* speak about $\sqrt 2$ meters exactly as well -- in fact I've just done that: "$\sqrt 2$ meters".

There's only a problem if you have *already* decided that *rational* numbers as lengths are somehow better or "more real" than algebraic reals. The usual response to your observation is that they aren't.

Many mathematicians are ready to afford some kind of privileged ontological status to the *integers*, but the mainstream position is that the *rationals* are really a man-made construct, to about the same degree that the real numbers are.

Comment: I mean computationally (theoretically) we know what is exact 1 m but we do not and cannot know what is exact $\sqrt 2$ while it is just the measurement of the ends of two exactly measured (even theoretically, if not practically) quantities placed at 90 degrees. Saying that we cannot measure exactly even 1 m defeats the purpose of the question

Comment: @user12345: Sure we can know what exactly $\sqrt 2$ is: it is $\sqrt 2$ exactly, and "$\sqrt2$" is just as exact a decription of a number as "$\frac{123772}{238837}$" is.

Comment: If 1 is man made and still exact then $\sqrt 2$ is man made but non exact why? when it is the outcome of some analysis involving exact numbers and angles

Comment: @user12345: You're the one who claims that $\sqrt2$ is not exact -- don't ask _me_ to justify your own faulty assumptions.

Comment: yes! $\sqrt 2$ is not exact because we don't know the value in real world i.e., it has to be solved to obtain a value which is real like 1, 2, 3, 1.5, 2.7 etc. we don't have to solve 1 or 2 but we do need to solve $\sqrt 2$ to get a value. If $\sqrt 2$ is exact why can't we know it's value as exact as we know 1 , 2 ,3 and so on

Comment: @user12345: What do you mean by "the value in the real world"? The value of $\sqrt 2$ is $\sqrt 2$, exactly -- every bit as exactly as $1.5$ is $1.5$. There is nothing "non-real" about either of these numbers. It looks like you think number with finite decimal representations are "more real" than other real numbers. Do you have any arguments for that strange positions (if it is yours)?

Comment: it is like saying the following: explaining something which cannot be measured and saying it is "immeasurable" and claiming that one has exactly measured it by saying that it is "immeasurable" and "immeasurable" is the exact measurement of that thing. it is injustice with the question

Comment: @user12345: You're speaking nonsense based on an apparently completely personal  meaning of most of the words you're using.

Comment: if someone says it is 1, 2, 3 or something no one will ask how much is that. But if someone says it is $\sqrt 2$ or $\sqrt 4$ (which one has to say it is 2) or it is $\sqrt 365793846595050$ or whatever one would ask the questions, What is that or how much is that? because mere stating that value will not answer the questioner. I think we are missing a point here though for one it might sound nonsense. I don't think it is non sense. I think what you are saying is more of a "nonscience"